# Updating a pre-exiting fields datatype(string=> date) in a mongoDb collection

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to update a field that was initially captured as a string instead of a date type.
Currently, the query that insert into the collection has been modified , so that future insert to that field is date. data type

However, I am trying to update the previously inserted data, before query modification that still has the string data type

Here is what I tried, but giving error

```
db.collection.update_one({“clusterTime”:{"$type":“string”}},{"$set":{“clusterTime:datetime.datetime.strptime(’$clusterTime’,’%y-%m-%d’).date()}})
```

I really would appreciate contributions.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post the full error

Comment: You're missing the closing quote around `{"$set":{"clusterTime:dateti`, should be `{"$set":{"clusterTime":dateti`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over the records using forEach, convert to date, and save the document

```
db.collectionName.find({ 'clusterTime' : { '$type' : 'string' }} ).forEach(function (doc) {   
  doc.clusterTime = new Date(doc.clusterTime); // convert field to date
  db.collectionName.save(doc);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The python version for updating the datatype

```
db.collection.update(
   {
      "clusterTime":{
         "$type":"string"
      }
   },
   [
      {
         "$set":{
            "clusterTime":{
               "$dateFromString":{
                  "dateString":"$clusterTime",
                  "format":"%Y-%m-%d"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
)
```